# Managing IIS through Delphi code

Tags: delphi, iis, inno-setup

I'm developing an Inno Setup installer and I need to manage an IIS server from my delphi code. I've googled how to add/remove ISAPI filters and how to create a virtual folder. However, I still need to be able to add/remove/list ISAPI extensions and create/remove websites. So my question is how can I do that?

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify -- is the Setup routine manipulating ISAPI stuff, or is your Delphi code doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS admin has a scripting interface, you should be able to call from either Delphi or InnoSetup or a combination of both:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526050(VS.90).aspx